# NHibernate custom table hierarchy

Tags: nhibernate

I am mapping the following entities using NHibernate:

```
+ Party (abstract)
  - Employee
  - Customer
```

I am using the mapping strategy called: **joined-subclass** in the following way:

```
<!-- Base PARTY entity-->
  <class name="PartyMap" abstract="true" table="Party">
    <id name="Id" column="PartyID">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <joined-subclass table="Customer" name="Customer">
      <key column="CustomerID" />
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass table="Employee" name="Employee">
      <key column="EmployeeID" />
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

My problem is that inside the **Party** table I have the following structure:

```
PartyTable
  PartyID
  EmployeeID
  CustomerID
```

While NHibernate use the **Id** field for every child table mapped. Should I use a different approach like component to achieve my goal?

Comment: How come you have these IDs (I mean `EmployeeID` and `CustomerID`)? Do you have influence on the schema?

Comment: No, it's an old database legacy that writes guid.empty if the reletionship is not satisfied

Comment: Perhaps you should use a many-to-one mapping then.

Comment: There you go, I had the same idea, it will completely break the structure of my POCOs but the logic of this hierarchy is quite different than a normal situation

Comment: Those `Guid.Empty` values will be problematic.  For one thing, they probably mean that there is no foreign key constraint on the relationship, so there could be bad data in the database.  NHibernate expects (very reasonably) that if a foreign key is not null, then there is a row that exists on the other side of the relationship.  There's a couple different ways to deal with this.

Comment: If `Guid.Empty` is the only bad value you have to worry about, then you can use a [nullable tuplizer](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.aspx) to turn those empty guids into nulls.  If there are lots of other bad values, then consider using [`not-found="ignore"`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone).  Be aware that this has [performance implications](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/relations-not-foundignore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution that I have found is to implement an event listner on top of NHibernate framework so that every time an entity is saved I can control the values passed and fix the error with the Guid without the need to create crazy Stored Procedures.
I know it's ugly but the database is legacy so there is not really much I can do